# echo doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, html

**Echo works fine at other lines** But when i try to add  tag to this table, i see that  tags placed out of the  tag.

```
    <table>
<th style="cursor:pointer;border-radius:5px 0px 0px 0px;">Başlık</th>
<th style="cursor:pointer;">Başlatan</th>
<th style="cursor:pointer;border-radius:0px 5px 0px 0px;">Tarih</th>

$sonuc = mysql_query("select A.subject, A.poster_name, A.poster_time, A.id_msg, A.id_topic, B.id_first_msg, B.id_member_started from smf_messages A, smf_topics B WHERE A.id_msg = B.id_first_msg ORDER BY id_topic DESC LIMIT 10");

if(mysql_num_rows($sonuc)!=0)
{
    while($oku = mysql_fetch_object($sonuc))
    {
        echo '<tr id="iceriktablo" style="cursor:pointer;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;">';
        echo '<a href="forum/index.php?topic='. $oku->id_topic .'"><td style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">';
        echo $oku->subject;
        echo '</td></a>';
        echo '<a href="forum/index.php?topic='. $oku->id_topic .'"><td style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;"><center><b>';
        echo $oku->poster_name;
        echo '</b></center></td></a>';
        echo '<td style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;"><center><b>';
        $zaman = $oku->poster_time;
        echo gmdate("d-m-Y\ H:i:s", $zaman);
        echo '</b></center></td></tr></a>';
    }
}else{
    echo "Hiçbir kayıt bulunamadı!";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>

</table>
```

result as inspect element: 
[http://puu.sh/qed4c/7b04611347.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW9zX.png)
result: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZnPd.png)
filename: index.php

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Where you want to add tag?

Comment: But my php version is 5.3.29 @Nasir i wanna add tag like this <a href="address"><tr> ... </tr></a>

Comment: Don't apply link on tr or td but apply on some text inside tds

Comment: @Nasir but i wanna make tr as link :(

Comment: @Nasir In that's case you need to bind a click event to the `tr`

Comment: @Aaron thank you. This is the solution i seek for. How i can close the topic?

Comment: The only [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) of a `<tr>` is `<td>` or `<th>`. You can make your `<tr>` act like a link using javascript by attaching a click event handler. And your PHP version has been [end of life](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for quite a while.

Comment: @SezerToker First of all, `id="iceriktablo"` in a while-loop is a bad idea

Comment: @Aaron why is it? Should i add style=".." ?

Comment: @SezerToker `id` should be unique to the entire document. Simply put, one-to-one mapping for a given `id` and an element. In the while loop, you can have one to many. Use `class` instead

Comment: Thank you, I will do that @Aaron I learned much from this site's society.

Comment: @SezerToker Chances are if you didn't know that fact, you are overstepping your boundaries and should go back to reviewing the basics before making database calls.

Comment: I am trying to learn everything i see but there is no proper lessons on web(in my language) to teach the subtleties of html, php or sql. So i am trying to learn with trying if fails asking. Sorry if i bother you with my questions. I will try to search deeply next time.

Comment: @SezerToker You're not bothering anyone. As for your immediate problem, I believe this would be the easiest way. https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid:

```
    echo '<a href="forum/index.php?topic='. $oku->id_topic .'"><td style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;"><center><b>';
    echo $oku->poster_name;
    echo '</b></center></td></a>';
```

The A-tag isn't allowed to wrap TD (and of course some more). I guess the browser corrected that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Tag `A` is not a part of a table to it will be always placed out of it. You can't do somethig like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <a><td></td></a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You should place your `A` tag inside `TD` or `TH` tag.